# forward class friend declaration

Tags: c++

Hi i have a problem, I try to do the follow, class A depends on class B and vice versa like this

```
class A;

 class B{
   A foo;
   friend B A::doSomething();

 };

class A {
   B bar;
   B doSomething;
};
```

The friend declartion does not work because A is an incomplete declartion. Is there any way to avoid this? (Swapp classes declaration order is not a solution I did not want to construct a more complicated example where swapping does not work anymore)

Comment: *Is there any way to avoid this?* Avoid the cyclic dependency in the first place. The rest will fall through by itself. What is it that you need to solve for which you think you need that dependency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're trying to do right now would make your classes **infinitely large** *(as I understand, `bar` and `foo` are class member variables, hence this means that `B` includes `A`, which includes `B`, ...).*

You could use pointers and store `A* foo` or `B* bar` in one of your classes or somehow **redesign** your application to avoid this *circular dependency.*

Answer (score 0):

Nest the two classes. This gives far more favourable rules about where and when you can declare and define what.

In addition, I'd suspect that your design may just be borked. You might want to post the actual innards of A and B so that we can give more advice.